# How to access an included module's methods from within another included module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, clearance

```
module Foo
  attr_accessor :val
end

module Bar
  def bar
    val = 50
  end
end

class FooBar
  include Foo
  include Bar
end

fb = FooBar.new
puts fb.bar # 50
puts fb.val # nil
```

I would like to, from within Bar, change Foo's "val" value.

Just so you know, I'm trying to do this because I want to add user authentication through a Facebook Canvas app in Clearance (0.8.2 (old, I know)). The variable that I want to change is https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/b8ccca00d91cb336e044b76b5c6ae1d8de9d2d8d/lib/clearance/authentication.rb#L25.

This module gets included into ApplicationController, and I'm including another module afterwards (FacebookAuthenticationHelper) that does something like

```
def authenticate_facebook
  current_user ||= facebook_user if coming_from_facebook?
end
```

I would love to know if there's a better way to do this as well. I'm not using OAuth, I'm just saving Facebook's user_id sends to my app from signed_request into my DB.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe `val = 50` in `Bar::bar` creates a local variable.  Does it work if you use `self.val = 50` instead?

Comment: You're right! That works. Thank you! Do you want to answer the question, so I can accept it?

Comment: Will do.  I was looking for the link where I learned that, but I can't seem to find it any more...  Maybe I get to write the new definitive guide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby, any statement of the form `varname = value` will create a local variable named `varname` if it doesn't already exist.  *This is even true within class methods where the class has a setter method of the same name.*  Furthermore, if a local variable exists, it takes precedence over getters and setters.  For example:

```
class Demo
    attr_accessor :foo

    def demonstrate!
        @foo = 1      #1: Set member variable foo, so we get meaningful output
        puts foo      #2: Prints 1 (this calls the getter)
        puts self.foo #3: Prints 1 (also calls the getter)

        foo = 2       #4: Creates a LOCAL variable named foo with the value 2
        puts foo      #5: Prints 2 (locals take precedence over getters)
        puts self.foo #6: Prints 1 (calls the getter - the member variable hasn't changed)

        self.foo = 3  #7: Use SELF to ensure you call a getter or setter
        puts foo      #8: Prints 2 (the local again)
        puts self.foo #9: Prints 3 (the member, which is now 3)
    end
end
```

The bad thing about this system is:  Look at lines 2 and 5.  *The same exact code does different things!*  On line 2, the local variable `foo` didn't exist yet, so ruby did the "next best" thing and called the getter.  But on line 5, the local `foo` exists, so it takes precedence.

I'd say that this is bad language design:  If setters can't be called without `self`, why should it be okay for getters - especially when it can lead to rickety, context-sensitive code like the above?  But it's what we have to work with, and it leads to some general guidelines:

1. If you can, use `@foo`.  It's obvious what that does.
2. If you're using a getter or setter, always use `self`, even when it's not strictly necessary.  This makes it obvious what you're calling.  It also guarantees your code won't behave differently if you add a local with the same name later.
3. If you do 1 and 2, you can assume that anything without a `@` or a `self` is a local variable (or a function call, but you can probably tell those apart by name).

And that ended up being a bit long-winded, but I was unable to find a good demonstration of the getter/setter/local problem to link to.  So maybe this is it - hope it's helpful!